# Should kingdom-hearts-3d be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Now that Kingdom Hearts 3 is finally released, it is only a matter of time before questions for [kingdom-hearts-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-3) start showing up.

There is currently the tag with a few questions under [kingdom-hearts-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-3d). For those who may start Kingdom Hearts 3 without at least some knowledge of previous Kingdom Hearts games, I am foreseeing there might be some general confusion or potential mis-tagged questions between [kingdom-hearts-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-3) and [kingdom-hearts-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-3d).

The official title for Kingdom Hearts 3D is "Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance". Should [kingdom-hearts-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-3d) be renamed to [kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance) to avoid any confusion in upcoming questions?

Comment: For someone new to the story, I would have seen 3D as in "it's a 3D game". Now once I did my research due to my massive confusion on the story, it would have made sense. But I think there should be a clear distinction between the two.

Comment: Now that the tag charlimit has been extended, this seems like a good idea to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done:

- [kingdom-hearts-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-3d) -> [kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-dream-drop-distance)